# Dart: How to Merge array based on ID?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an complex list but I need to merge them plz help me..

```
    var itemlist1=[
      {"p_id": "a101", "p_name": "item1","type": "finished"},
      {"p_id": "a102", "p_name": "item2","type": "s-finished"},
      {"p_id": "b101", "p_name": "item3","type": "finished"},
      {"p_id": "c105", "p_name": "item4","type": "finished"}];

var itemlist2=[
      {"p_id": "a101", "type": "finished", "quantity": 605, "price": 1200},
      {"p_id": "a102", "type": "semi finished", "quantity": 150, "price": 950},     
      {"p_id": "c105", "type": "finished", "quantity": 560, "price":665}];
```

i need list like below.

```
var itemlist3=[
{"p_id": "a101", "p_name": "item1", "type": "finished", "quantity": 605, "price": 1200},
{"p_id": "a102", "p_name": "item2", "type": "s-finished", "quantity": 150, "price": 950},    
{"p_id": "b101", "p_name": "item3", "type": "finished", "quantity": 0, "price": 0},      
{"p_id": "c105", "p_name": "item4", "type": "finished", "quantity": 560, "price":665}];
```

how to achive this ? help me..

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.  This question does not seem fundamentally different from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71268462/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so your result list takes the `p_id`, `p_name` and type from the first list, like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = itemList1.map((item) {
  var resultItem = Map.from(item);
  return resultItem;
});
```

However you also want to add `quantity` and `price` from the second list, like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = itemList1.map((item) {
  var resultItem = Map.from(item);
  var list2Obj = itemList2.firstWhereOrNull((value) => value['p_id'] == item['p_id']);
  var quantity = list2Obj != null ? list2Obj['quantity'] : 0;
  var price = list2Obj != null ? list2Obj['price'] : 0;

  resultItem['quantity'] = quantity;
  resultItem['price'] = price;

  return resultItem;
});
```

I used the `firstWhereOrNull` function from the `package:collection` module. If you don't want to use it, here is a simple implementation:

```
T? firstWhereOrNull<T>(List<T> list, bool Function(T) fun) {
  try {
    return list.FirstWhere(fun);
  } on StateError {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I can't test the implementation right now, but it should work

Comment: Thank you sir.. got the correct output..

Comment: this answer is very helpfull , and easy ..

Answer (score 2):

You want to merge two `List<Map>`s such that `Map`s that have the same `p_id` value are combined.  To make it easy and fast to find an existing `Map` from a `p_id` value, it'd help to first create a `Map<String, Map>` to use as a lookup table to map `p_id` values to `Map`s.  As we iterate over the `List`s, we'll merge each `Map` with an existing entry in the table.  Two `Map`s can be easily merged with the spread operator.

Once that's done, we can create a `List<Map>` from the values of the table.

For example:

```dart
var itemlist1 = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
  {"p_id": "a101", "p_name": "item1", "type": "finished"},
  {"p_id": "a102", "p_name": "item2", "type": "s-finished"},
  {"p_id": "b101", "p_name": "item3", "type": "finished"},
  {"p_id": "c105", "p_name": "item4", "type": "finished"}
];

var itemlist2 = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
  {"p_id": "a101", "type": "finished", "quantity": 605, "price": 1200},
  {"p_id": "a102", "type": "semi finished", "quantity": 150, "price": 950},
  {"p_id": "c105", "type": "finished", "quantity": 560, "price": 665}
];

void main() {
  var mergedMap = <String, Map<String, dynamic>>{};

  for (var map in itemlist1.followedBy(itemlist2)) {
    var id = map['p_id']!;
    var existingEntry = mergedMap[id] ?? {};
    mergedMap[id] = {...existingEntry, ...map};
  }

  var itemlist3 = mergedMap.values.toList();
  
  print(itemlist3);
}
```

Presuming that there's a constant number of entries for each `Map`, this approach should be O(m + n) where *m* and *n* are the sizes of the two `List<Map>`s to merge.

Comment: than you sir. I am able to merge list but {"p_id": "b101", "p_name": "item3", "type": "finished", "quantity": 0, "price": 0},    is not getting correct. but still your code helped thank you

Comment: Is there any way to just take some fields instead of them all? I have the field 'title' in both columns and its causing issues in other areas of code. Thank you

Comment: @user237462 I don't understand what you mean.  If you want to spread a `Map` but omit a particular key, then no, that's not directly possible.  You'd have to remove those keys before spreading those `Map`s.

Comment: @Jamesdlin I managed to find a solution List 
      for(int i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < venues.length; j++){
          if (events[i]["venueId"] == events[j]["venueId"]){
            events[i]["venueId"]= events[j]["venueId"];
            list3.add({"title" : events[i]['title'], "date" :  events[i]['date'], "imageUrl" :  events[i]['imageUrl'],"djs" :  events[i]['djs'], "venueTitle" :  venues[j]['title']});
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      list3.sort((a,b)=> a["date"].compareTo(b["date"]));
      return list3;

Comment: Just in case anyone else is wondering. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it by looping one of the list and getting its corresponding value from the other list. Then merge them.

```dart
var itemlist1 = [
      {"p_id": "a101", "p_name": "item1","type": "finished"},
      {"p_id": "a102", "p_name": "item2","type": "s-finished"},
      {"p_id": "b101", "p_name": "item3","type": "finished"},
      {"p_id": "c105", "p_name": "item4","type": "finished"}];

    var itemlist2 = [
      {"p_id": "a101", "type": "finished", "quantity": 605, "price": 1200},
      {"p_id": "a102", "type": "semi finished", "quantity": 150, "price": 950},     
      {"p_id": "c105", "type": "finished", "quantity": 560, "price":665}];
  
    var itemlist3 = itemlist2.map((map){
      var _matches = itemlist1.where((val)=> val['p_id'] == map['p_id']);
      if(_matches.isNotEmpty){
        return {..._matches.first, ...map};
      }
    }).toList();
```

Comment: thank you sir.. but I'm not getting correct result that I wanted..